# Error when importing data from SQL dumps to MIMIC-III tables

Tags: mimic-iii

I am having trouble importing data to the created MIMIC-III tables. I followed the installing MIMIC locally instruction on mimic.physionet.org and failed at step 6. When I enter the code, it outputs an error message: `ERROR: character with byte sequence 0x8f in encoding "WIN1252" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"`.

My OS is Windows 10 and I am using PostgreSQL 9.5. I created my tables in the default Postgres database, the encoding is UTF8. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: have you made any progress with this? I am currently in a similar situation struggling to install MIMIC locally. I tried to send a private message but I am unsure if there is a way to do that on here.

Comment: Going to give it a go tonight on my Windows 7 machine. I didn't have problems last time, so it might be something new in Windows 10 causing a conflict.

Comment: I ran it within PostgreSQL 9.5 on Windows 7 by launching psql shell and running:

`\i D:/work/mimic-code/buildmimic/postgres/postgres_load_data.sql`

@J.McClelland You could try running it interactively instead of with -f, but I have a feeling that won't fix it. It's probably a Windows 10 specific issue... unfortunately I don't have access to a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I have tried it again on both windows 8 and ubuntu, but the problem remains. I have also read several solutions which I found on the Internet but I still haven't manage to fix it yet.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the MD5 checksums of the decompressed CSVs match those in the checksum file?

Comment: So, I have found a solution to this problem. In the postgres_load_data.sql file, there should be name of the .csv files and what you need to do is changing the name of those file to match the name of the decompressed .csv files and run the SQL file as in the instructions. Good luck guys